# mutex inside empty in concurrent queue

Tags: c++, thread-safety

according to Anthony Williams "c++ concurrency in action" book, threadsafe_queue implemented in a way like this:

```
template<typename T>
class thredsafe_queue
{
public:
    ...
    bool empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard(internal_mutex_);
        return data_queue_.empty();
    }
    ...
};
```

**1.** my first question is about internal lock in empty call:
 code like this

```
while(our_threasafe_queue.empty())
     do_something()
```

isn't threadsafe anyway, with lock inside empty call or without; of cource, we can make it threadsafe using external mutex. but goal of internal lock is still unclear.

**2.**second is about expediency of public empty function in threadsafe_queue.

Comment: Isn't that just an example showing that you cannot have a thread-safe queue with an `empty()` method?

Comment: """Even though empty() is a const member function, and the other parameter to the copy constructor is a const reference, other threads may have non- const references to the object, and be calling mutating member functions, so we still need to lock the mutex. Since locking a mutex is a mutating operation, the mutex object must be marked mutable B so it can be locked in empty() and in the copy constructor.""" - it's all that author said about empty call